# NodeJS exhausting the heap space as I read large JSON files in a loop

Tags: node.js, v8, heap-memory

I have around 220 JSON files each around 6MB that I need to parse and process. So, I am doing this in a loop. Here is how I read and process it:

```
        let fileList = fs.readdirSync('/500gb/json_files/gnip_30_p2');
        fileList = fileList.reverse();
        let totalErrors = 0;
        let totalFiles = 0;
        for (let file of fileList) { // TOTAL 220 FILES
            // READ EACH JSON FILE OF ~6MB
            let records = require(`/500gb/json_files/gnip_30_p2/${file}`);
            let results = records.results;
            if (results) {
                for (let record of results) {
                    // .. Some Processing Work Here ..
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem with this is, after running for around 3 minutes, I get `JavaScript heap out of memory` error:

```
[3661:0x28af890]    50503 ms: Mark-sweep 1310.9 (1467.4) -> 1310.7 (1470.9) MB, 612.9 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[3661:0x28af890]    51132 ms: Mark-sweep 1310.7 (1470.9) -> 1310.7 (1434.4) MB, 627.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[3661:0x28af890]    51759 ms: Mark-sweep 1310.7 (1434.4) -> 1310.7 (1429.4) MB, 626.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
```

There is no recursive call, only looping, reading and then submitting the read data after some modifications to a service which responds quickly. What could then be the reason for NodeJS exhausting the heap space? Is this not the correct way of reading large JSON files and processing them?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to read a file that is too big with "require"

Comment: Maybe due to `require`, try to use `fs` instead.

Comment: @inneedofhelp Okay. Are there any defined limits? Also, the error occurs after 2-3 minutes, till the time some files have already been required and processed. Also, doesn't the scope of require help in emptying the heap?

Comment: @SuhailGupta it's a misuse of require, which is specifically designed for module loading - see http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Comment: If you're just reading a file then I'd go with what @everett1992 suggested but if you need it required which has some other meanings then I'd search a way to enlarge the memory used by node process.

Comment: @SuhailGupta - Try once on node@10.10 version (if not already done)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `require` for anything other than requiring modules. `require` does some caching, so you're keeping every file you've read in memory.

Use `fs.readFile` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere, you’re loading everything into memory.

@everett1992 suggestion is a good one, but you ought to look up why.

Using ‘streams’ only keeps ‘chunks’ of the file in memory.  With streams, you can pipe the results into other functions...

Look up the quoted terms, there are a lot of good articles.

Answer (score 0):

Try either

- Only reading the file right before processing the data, and releasing it afterwords.
  For example replace `require(filepath);` with `JSON.parse(fs.ReadFileSync(filepath, 'utf8'));`
- Preparing the files beforehand. eg. cut a file into smaller chunks

---

This is not limited to `require`.

HTTP requests and `fs.ReadFile()` will throw `Javascript heap out of memory` for large files. (Images, JSON, etc)

Related: `--max-old-space-size=xxxx` does not solve this. There is a distinction between memory for processes and memory for buffers. [See this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2738#issuecomment-294354111).

~
Personally iv'e never solved this to comfortably provide a better solution other than preparing your files before reading them.

Update : have a look at [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) for large JSON file